# Java regex to check that string contains more than 2 words and has digits

Tags: java, regex

I am writing a regex to match the string containing more than 2 words and should have at least 1 digit available or 1 word with no digits.

i.e If I have following strings:

```
1. "Sample data with no digit" (no digit)
2. "1004" (less than 2 words)
3. "1004 1008" (no alphabets)
4. "1004 data" (exactly 2 words)
5. "5ample Data with digits" (note that S-> 5)
6. "Sample Data with 1004"
```

The regex should match the 5th,6th strings (reason for not fetching others is mentioned along with the data)

I tried following but the following always returns all the strings:

```
[\d[0-9]|[ABEGFIHKJLOQPSRUTXZbgfihkjloqpsuz!]]+[\w\s]* (returns all strings)
```

Please note that I am using JAVA.

Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: What about "Everest, Eiger, K2", i.e. what do you mean by a word?

Comment: try this `([0-9]|[a-zA-Z]){2,}\s*`

Comment: Yes, it is a valid string and it should be fetched. A word can be considered whenever we get a space. So, in this we have 3 words.

Comment: @Lino, The regex shared is matching "data" String and not "data data 2"

Comment: And what about punctuation? Such as commas, dots, question marks, etc...

Comment: Are you sure you want "at least 1 digit available **or** 1 word with no digits"? Because string 1 should pass if it's "or".

Comment: @NothingNothing, I would ignore the punctuations...

Comment: "should have at least 1 digit available or 1 word with no digits" - this does not make sense, as any alphanumeric string meets this requirement.

Comment: @TomWyllie, Yes, In short the requirement can be stated that the string has at least 1 alphanumeric word or a Number.

Comment: What do you mean by "an alphanumeric word"? Would you consider `"the"` to be an alphanumeric word? (it technically is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex with 2 lookahead assertions:

```
^(?=.*\b[a-zA-Z]*\d+[a-zA-Z]*)(?=.*\b[a-zA-Z]+\b)(?:\w+\h+){2,}\w+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rnfR5S/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `(?=.*\b[a-zA-Z]*\d+[a-zA-Z]*)`: Lookahead to ensure we have a word with a digit
- `(?=.*\b[a-zA-Z]+\b)`: Lookahead to assert we have a word with no digit
- `(?:\w+\h+){2,}\w+`: Make sure we have at least 3 words in input

Comment: This is working. However I had to replace {2,} with {1,} to make it work with "data te8st"

Comment: To ensure 2 or more words use: `^(?=.*\b[a-zA-Z]*\d+[a-zA-Z]*)(?=.*\b[a-zA-Z]+\b)\w+\h+\w+`